# How do I access Collection keys during For Each in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, associative-array

I have some code like this:

```
Dim col As Collection = New Collection
col.Add(value1, "key1")
col.Add(value2, "key2")

' later...
For Each item As String In col
    ' want to get valueX and keyX here; currently, "item" holds the value
Next
```

How can I get both the value and key within the loop? Maybe there is another class that makes this easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a generic dictionary...

```
 Imports System.Collections.Generic  'at top of file

    Dim col As New Dictionary(Of String, Of Object) 'or whatever type
    col.Add("key1", value1)
    col.Add("key2", value2)    

    For Each item as KeyValuePair(of String, Object) in col
           Console.WriteLine(item.key & ": " & item.value)
    Next
```

Comment: I'm getting the error, "KeyValuePair is not defined". Any ideas?

Comment: `Imports System.Collections.Generic`